# what doese it mean $C(\mathbb{R}^+,L^1(\mathbb{R}))$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Can someone tell me what does it mean to say $u\in C(\mathbb{R}^+,L^1(\mathbb{R}))$ ?

I don't know if this is true but what I understood from the demonstration that I am doing , is that lim $\int_\mathbb{R}|u(t,x)-u(t_0,x)|dx=0 $ when $t\rightarrow t_0$ for all $t_0\in \mathbb{R}^+  $

Answer (score 0):

It means the set of all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^+$(with Euclidean topology) to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$(with norm topology induced by $L^1$ norm)

In your case, $u$ takes two variables. $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $y \in\mathbb{R}$. If you keep $x$ fixed, then $u(x,\cdot)$ becomes a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Henry W. is it equivalent to what i wrote ?

Comment: @M.luffy Yes. They are equivalent.